# Exception JSF Delete from Database

Tags: java, jpa, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a problem with my exception handling in JSF.

I want to show an error message on my JSF page when the user can not delete an entry in the database.

```html
<h:message for="deleteButton"/>
<h:commandButton id="deleteButton" value="Delete" action="#{filmView.deleteRow(film)}"/>
```

---

```
public void deleteRow(Film deleteTemp) {
  filmService.delete(deleteTemp.getFilmId());
}

public void delete(int id) {
  try {
    em.createQuery("delete from Film where film_id=" + id).executeUpdate();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", new FacesMessage(
    "Removing dataset(ID:" 
     + id + ") is not possible, because it's used in another dataset!"));
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get this error message into the JSF page and if yes is this better, because I heard that how I do it right now, it is not a good solution.

Comment: Why is not a good solution? Does it work or not? Try to identify your problem: is it jpa related or jsf? Can you catch the exception? Can you show a Faces Message?

Comment: @perissf It is working, but my problem is that i went from the bottom layer directly to the view and not go from one layer to another and I thought it would be possible to do the exception handling directly on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your ManagedBean should handle screen messages:

1. The best way is throw the error from DAO to your Service layer.
2. On Service layer you can throw again to your `ManagedBean` and show the message.

---

On your FilmDAO.java:

```
public void delete(int id) throws Exception {
    em.createQuery("delete from Film where film_id=" + id).executeUpdate();
}
```

On your FilmService.java:

```
public void delete(int id) throws Exception {
    filmDAO.delete(id);
}
```

On your FilmMB.java:

```
try {
  filmService.delete(id);
} catch (Exception e) {
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", 
    new FacesMessage("Removing dataset(ID:" + id + ") is not possible, 
                      because it's used in another dataset!"));
}
```